# How to set Cookies on Html file?

Tags: javascript, html, session-cookies

Enyone helps me on how insert cookie name with values & specific site domain in local html file?

Any methods will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a document about cookie implementation on Javascript: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Also I suggest you to use the HTML5 web storage implementation `localStorage`. Its way simple to understand.

```
localStorage.setItem("myName", "Jhon Sapiera");
//set a new local storage variable.

alert(localStorage.getItem("myName"));
//get the variable - use it.
```

Read all about it: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Thanks for response, If someone uses my html file the cookie will store in his Browser?

Comment: No, cookie and the localStorage unit both works on the browser, so the actual "data" is in the computer that the cookie was created. Moving html file to another computer will not move the cookie data.